# rowData remains on first record after filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When using the filter box of a datatable, the `rowId` remains on the first record, and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the datatable (simplified as much as possible):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'process/getData.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data); 
      var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
        "data": jsonObject,
        "columns": [  
          {
            "data": "MONDAY",
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
            {
              $(nTd).html("<span class='checkMon'>+oData.MONDAY+</span>");
            },
            // columns for each work day
          }
        ],
        "paging": false,
        "scrollY": 730,
        "scrollX": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "autoWidth": true
      });
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('fail: '+ errorThrown);
      return false;
    }
});
```

Outside of the datatable, I have `onclick` event handler:

```
$('#example1').on('click', 'tr > td > .checkMon', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable();
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var data = $dataTable.rows().data();
  var rowData = data[tr.index()];

  console.log(rowData.UID);
});
```

Prior to filtering, when I click any cell, the console reads the correct `rowData.UID`.

The problem is when I filter and click the cell again, the console reads the first row's `rowData.UID`.

Does anyone see why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Your answer was helpful, however I was able to solve the problem by using a data-attribute in the datatable.  I will be posting my answer.  I gave your answer an upvote.  You helped me on back-to-back questions.  I do appreciate that.

Comment: Hopefully, you took into account my suggestion to use `ajax` option, because your current method is error prone and I've seen it causing troubles for too many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is simply log into the console `UID` property of the object that sourced the row that holds the `<span>` you've clicked, following approach should work:

```
$('#example1').on('click', '.checkMon', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  const dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable();
  const rowData = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
  console.log(rowData.UID);
});
```

Also, consider using [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option. With that you won't need to waste performance destroying/re-creating your table and that will make your code cleaner and safer.

Comment: I had to make an alteration to my application.  With that said, that code you provided does indeed solve my problem.  Thank you again, sir.